# sysdate-1 not working in Oracle Jobs

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

I have a stored procedure in Oracle. I want to call it in JOBS of Oracle.

```
DECLARE 
  P_DATE   DATE;
  BEGIN    

  P_DATE := TO_DATE ('19/10/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY');

  MITRA.PENJUALAN_ANTAR_CABANG.REPORTKONSOLRK ( P_DATE );
  COMMIT; 
END;
```

the result is right when I execute P_DATE as '19/10/2016'. But when I change it like this below the result is not display.

```
DECLARE
   P_DATE   DATE;
BEGIN
   P_DATE := TO_DATE (TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1), 'DD/MM/YYYY');

   MITRA.PENJUALAN_ANTAR_CABANG.REPORTKONSOLRK (P_DATE);
   COMMIT;
END;
```

What is my query mistake, while if I run `select trunc(SYSDATE-1) from dual` the date was right.

Comment: What exactly happens when you use `TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1)`?

Comment: the result is 10/19/2016. but when I put it in  P_DATE := TO_DATE (TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1), 'DD/MM/YYYY'); is not working

Comment: ***Never***, ever call `to_date()` on a `DATE` value. Just don't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SYSDATE - 1` is already a `date`. Passing it to `to_date` will produce a syntax error. Just drop the `to_date` call and you should be fine:

```
P_DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1);
```